# c# JIT and static constructors again

Tags: c#, static, constructor, jit

Okay i have a little problem with those 2 things up there

following situation:
I got an abstract class "Emitter". this class has a static Dictionary to keep track of all types deriving from it.

for Example i have the class "LinearEmitter" this class has a static constructor. this constructor adds the typeof(LinearEmitter) to the dictionary. the problem is now, when i want to use the static dictionary from Emitter (static method "getMeEmitterFromID(int id)") it can happen, that the children of "Emitter" (e.g. LinearEmitter) were not initialized (im reading data from a file and then look up the id from the classes in "Emitter" and initialize an instance from that).

how can i make sure that every Child-class is initialized before?(has written itself in the dictionary) ?

of course others should use this library, and they should also use the static constructor to add their Classes to the "Emitter"'s Dictionary

any ideas?

Comment: Can you share a broader context here? I´m just guessing that there is an alternative approach where you wouldn´t have to rely on a static dictionary somewhere.

Comment: Whats the importance of knowing which types derive from Emitter? Wouldn't it suffice to know if any type derives from Emitter at all? Eg. reverse your logic and use something like  LinearEmitter.GetType().BaseType

Comment: im reading a file. in the file im reading for example a 5. if the emitter with the id 5 is not yet in the dictionary i cant load that emitter.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert just had a great series about static constructors.

[Static Constructors Part One](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/),
[Static Constructors Part Two](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/11/static-constructors-part-two/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=static-constructors-part-two),
[Static Constructors Part Three](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/14/static-constructors-part-three/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=static-constructors-part-three),
[Static Constructors Part Four](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/18/static-constructors-part-four/)

To sum the useful bit up in your case: Static constructors get invoked by

1. just before the first access of a static method/field.
2. just before the first access to an instance of the type.

So you either invoke a static method like `Initialize()` or instantiate a class of the type derived from `Emitter`.

That aside, I'm sure there's a better way to implement your problem because the way static initializers run could change over different `.NET` / `CLR` versions and I wouldn't rely on that if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out. The fourth and final part is here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/18/static-constructors-part-four/

Comment: Added it to the links,and its me to say thank you @EricLippert. I really enjoy your blog!

Answer (score 0):

I would not expose the Dictionary itself, but instead make it an implementation detail. Then you can make a method like `GetByType(Type typeToGetFromDictionary)`. Now, the get method can lazily load the pieces it does not already have.

That being said, I agree with the comments that you should possibly rethink the architecture as this might not even be necessary.

Comment: the problem is, all i get from the file is a number. and now i have to get the type to that number, and reflection over all loaded assemblies would be the last thing i want in there (this thing is a game, and reflection kills speed a bit)